# Creating objects using a loop (Powershell GUI)

Tags: powershell

How can you create clone objects using a loop so that you can access each of them individually? For example 10 buttons:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {

   $Obj = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

   $Obj.Left = 30 * $i + 10
   $Obj.Top = 10
   $Obj.Width = 30
   $Obj.Height = 30

   $Form.Controls.Add($Disk)
}
```

And then make assignments in the script, let's say the text:

```
$Obj1.Text = 'One'
$Obj2.Text = 'Two'
...
$Obj10.Text = 'Ten'
```

Somehow, in the loop, it is necessary to specify the names of the objects $Obj1, $Obj2...$Obj10. Perhaps using this:

```
$Obj = New-Variable -Name ('Obj' + [string]$i)
```

But my knowledge is not so good to do it right away. Thanks for answers.

Comment: why not use the array? something like `$Obj[$Index].Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Add flow layout panel
$FlowLayoutPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$FlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection=[System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection]::LeftToRight
$FlowLayoutPanel.Dock=[System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Left
$FlowLayoutPanel.Width=200
$FlowLayoutPanel.BorderStyle=[System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.Controls.Add($FlowLayoutPanel)

#define click event for button
$Button_Click = 
{param($sender,$eventarg)

[System.Windows.Forms.Button] $currentbutton=$sender

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You have click on : " +  $currentbutton.Text, "My Dialog Box")
}



#Add Button into flow layout panel and associate event for every button
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {

   $Obj = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
   $Obj.Width = 80
   $Obj.Height = 30
   $Obj.Text="Button$i" 
   $Obj.Add_Click($Button_Click)

   $FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($Obj)
}



$result = $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```